# Domain Controller etiquette after a crash between Server 2003 & Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have 2 domain controllers on a non-Internet connected network running Windows Server 2008 R2. They running RAID 5 on a 8 Hard Drive server. Sometime last week the Boot Sector became corrupt on DC1 and I was unable to recover the server. I am not going to have to rebuild the server. I have been reading about the changes from Server 2003 to Server 2008. DC1 was the main domain controller and now that it won't but it is all falling to DC2. I know that in previous versions of Windows Server you had to make on the primary and one the secondary. Since DC2 does not see DC1 anymore is there anything I need to do to DC2 as it is now the one in control? I am thinking some kind of meta data clean up but I can't find any hard information on what procedure to do. I understand as of Server 2008 domain controllers are on an equal footing and provide replication to each other so they should be the same correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in saying that domain controllers are not "primary" or "secondary" anymore (although a bit incorrect on the timing: this became reality when Active Directory was first introduced in Windows 2000, and the whole "PDC/BDC" thing ceased to exist with Windows NT 4).

However, there *are* some things that are specifically done on a single domain controller at a time, and those are called the [FSMO roles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197132/active-directory-fsmo-roles-in-windows); if the failed DC held one or more of them, you'll have to forcibly transfer ("seize") them to the remaining one: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816779(v=ws.10).aspx.

Also, you'll have some cleaning up to do in Active Directory, by removing all references to the dead DC: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907(v=ws.10).aspx.

Last but not least, after you finish cleaning up your AD, bring up another domain controller as soon as possible; ***you should never run an Active Directory domain with a single DC***, because if *that* breaks too, you'll just find yourself with no domain anymore.

Comment: Thanks I did have a print out on directions on this. Thanks for the link. I will get to it ASAP! If the two DCs were working together before and DC1 went down I am guessing DC2 would not take up the FSMO because it was the second DC added to the domain correct?

Comment: Correct: if a DC holds one or more roles and it goes down, they need to be seized manually. Also, the failed DC must **NOT** be brought online again after this is done.

Comment: I will move over the FSMO. The other DC must be rebuilt with Windows Server 2008 R2 and brought back up. After the clean up it should get a new SID when rejoined no?

Comment: Yes, if you reinstall the OS you'll get a completely different computer, as far as AD is concerned; you can even use the same computer name and IP address of the failed DC.

Answer (score 1):

This [procedure](https://www.petri.com/seizing_fsmo_roles) perfectly fits your needs. It is called seizing and is used to transfer FSMO Roles between a "death" and a "working" DC.

> The process of moving the FSMO role from a non-operational role holder
>   to a different DC is called Seizing...

If you want to know more before following the how to, [read this](https://www.petri.com/understanding_fsmo_roles_in_ad).

Just, when you're done, never ever bring DC1 up again after this.

I warn you to rename the server to DC3 or something else whether you plan to reinstall it in the future.