# Domain controller failed on domain, how do I remove it?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, domain-controller

We had a server called `DC01` set as a domain controller. Then we got another server and added it to the domain as a backup domain controller `DC02`. Months after adding `DC02` to the domain `DC01` had a catastrophic failure and was unplugged/taken off the network. But `DC02` still things `DC01` exists and I get errors like

> The specified domain controller could not be contacted. This affects the following domain in the console.
>       Domain: domain.com
>   The error was: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>   Please choose from the following options:
>   [ ] Choose a different domain controller
>   [ ] Retry
>   [ ] Remove this domain from the console

Choosing a different domain controller leads me to the following:

> Current domain controller: (blank)
>   Look in this domain:
>   domain.com
>   Change to:
>   [x] The domain controller with the Operations Master token for the PDC emulator
>   [ ] Any available domain controller
>   [ ] Any available domain controller running Windows Server 2003 or later
>   [ ] This domain controller:
>   dc01.domain.com
>   dc02.domain.com

I select **This domain controller** and choose **dc02.domain.com** and the pop up goes away.

How do I get rid of the references to the old primary domain controller, dc01? And what must I do to dc02 to make it the new primary domain controller?

Comment: @Marco, I think you're right. His situation is almost identical to mine.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the first thing you need to do is seize the FSMO roles and transfer them to DC02

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/255504/using-ntdsutil-exe-to-transfer-or-seize-fsmo-roles-to-a-domain-control

Then you need to cleanup the metadata in Active directory to remove references to the old controller.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907(WS.10).aspx

Comment: That's why it's quite a duplicate of many questions such as: https://serverfault.com/q/869700/216275