# AD PDC and SDC domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, subdomain

We have PDC and SDC on our network.
I need clarification if our PDC server fail due to server fault, how to make SDC as acting PDC. What is the purpose of two DC's on same network. If PDC fail SDC will not act as PDC automatically. Pls clarify me i am new to DC's applicaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Primary and Secondary Domain Controllers hasn't really existed since Windows Server 2000.  They've been replaced by Active Directory.

If you have a domain controller that has failed and your other domain controllers don't pick up the slack, it's possible that one or more [FSMO roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_single_master_operation) were housed on the dead server.  If you're unable to restore the old DC, you might have to [seize those roles and assign them to other domain controllers](https://serverfault.com/questions/869700/domain-controller-etiquette-after-a-crash-between-server-2003-server-2008).

The purpose of multiple domain controllers on the same network is to provide redundancy, allowing you to patch, etc., without interruption of services.  It's best practice to gracefully decommission a dying DC if possible.  Gracefully decommissioning your DC (demoting it, in other words) will transfer the operation roles.

Multiple DCs are not a backup strategy.  Domain controllers should be backed up like any server.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i got clarity from your answer. Keep doing well.